# Dependent comboboxes in subform

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I have a main form which has one subform with two comboboxes. I want to limit the second combobox based on choice of first combobox. I added this code in rowsource of the first combobox:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblAll.Country FROM tblAll ORDER BY tblAll.Country;
```

and then in after update event of first combobox I added

```
Private Sub cboCountry_AfterUpdate()

    On Error Resume Next

    cboCity.RowSource = "Select tblAll.City " & _
            "FROM tblAll " & _
            "WHERE tblAll.Country = '" & cboCountry.Value & "' " & _
            "ORDER BY tblAll.City;"

End Sub
```

My problem is when I choose one value for second combobox, I can change first combobox to all option that I have in combobox one.

For example, first I choose France in first combobox, then second combo shows me cities of France, and I choose one. Now I can change combobox one to US.

It means I have one city from France in second combobox, and now I changed value of first combobox to US, and if I save this record and want to save another record in subform, it is possible.

What should I do to limit it? I mean when I choose city from second combobox, I dont want to have this possibility to change value of first combobox, because in this situation my database is wrong - I can save cities which don't belong to specific countries.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't user be able to change country in case they selected wrong one?

Have code in the AfterUpdate event of first combobox that deletes data from the second combobox (set the combobox value to Null) so user must now select an appropriate city.

If you don't want to allow user to change country after selecting city, then have to disable or lock the country combobox. Then reactivate it when moving to a new record. Will probably also want to disable/lock when re-opening existing records. So set the country combobox as disabled/locked in design and then programmatically activate it for only new record.

Recommend your code to set combobox 2 RowSource be in combobox 2 GotFocus event.

Comment: sorry I am new to access.I added 
Me.cityName = Null
 in the after update of first combobox , but nothing changed.
when I choose value for second combobox still I can change value of first combobox to all options that I have.

Comment: actually I have to design data entry form which allows user to edit data , user wants to have this possibility to change country when at first he enters the wrong one, so if he enter wrong country and city , he can change it. but problem is if he chose country and according to it, choose city, now he also have this possibilty to change country to what ever he wants , that means he can save wrong info.

Comment: Which is exactly why I recommend the code that sets city combobox value to Null when the country is selected.